# Ninject 2 and MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ninject

I've updated a project to VS2010 and MVC2 from VS2008 and MVC1. I'm having problems with Ninject not finding controllers within Areas

Here is my global.asax.cs file:

```cs
namespace Website
{
// Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
// visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    public static StandardKernel NinjectKernel;

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Balance",
            "Balance/{action}/{month}/{year}",
            new { controller = "Balance", action = "Index", month = DateTime.Now.Month, year = DateTime.Now.Year }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    /*
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        // initializes the NHProfiler so you can see what is going on with your queries
        HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
    }
    */

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var errorService = NinjectKernel.Get<IErrorLogService>();
        errorService.LogError(HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException(), "AppSite");
    }

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        if (NinjectKernel == null)
        {
            NinjectKernel = new StandardKernel(new ServiceModule());
        }

        return NinjectKernel;
    }
}

public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IHelper>().To<Helper>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<IErrorLogService>().To<ErrorLogService>();

        Bind<INHSessionFactory>().To<NHSessionFactory>().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(ctx =>
                                         ctx.Kernel.Get<INHSessionFactory>().GetSessionFactory())
                               .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<INHSession>().To<NHSession>();
        Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<INHSession>().GetSession());
    }
}
}
```

Accessing controllers within the /Controllers folder works OK, but accessing controllers within a /Areas/Member/Controller throws the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Cannot be null
Parameter name: service

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Cannot be null
Parameter name: service

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 
[ArgumentNullException: Cannot be null
Parameter name: service]
Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.GetResolutionIterator(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, Func`2 constraint, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Boolean isOptional, Boolean isUnique) +193
Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +41
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +66
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +124
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8771488
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30128; ASP.NET     Version:4.0.30128.1
```

The Url for this request is /Member/Controller/, If I change the Url too /Controller the controller fires but I get an error that the system cannot find the View in the path /Views

When it should be looking in /Area/Members/Views

I have either done something wrong in the upgrade or I'm missing something bt I just can't figure out what. I've been trying to figure this out for 3 days...

Comment: I get the same error using Castle Windsor.

Comment: @Carles good to know its not just me

Comment: You should be able to set a breakpoint on NinjectControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance, could you double check the Request URL and report back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update from the core, I just committed a fix: http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc

-Ian

Comment: @Ian thanks for that I'll try and check it out this weekend if I can find some time.